# Titanium Appcelerator SubView not Working in IOS

Tags: android, ios, titanium, cross-platform

Right now I have an application with a sliding menu. The main window has a view that is the 'main body view'. When a user selects an item from the sliding menu, it changes which view is added to the main body view. Here is the .xml for index:

```
    <Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <View id="menuview">
            <View id="menuheaderview">
                <Label id="menuheaderlabel">Menu</Label>
            </View>
            <View id="menubodyview">
                <TableView id="menutableview" onClick="select">
                    <TableViewRow class="menurowview">
                        <Label class="menulabel">News</Label>
                    </TableViewRow>
                    <TableViewRow class="menurowview">
                        <Label class="menulabel">Calendar</Label>
                    </TableViewRow>
                    <TableViewRow class="menurowview">
                        <Label class="menulabel">Homework</Label>
                    </TableViewRow>
                    <TableViewRow class="menurowview">
                        <Label class="menulabel">Classes</Label>
                    </TableViewRow>
                    <TableViewRow class="menurowview">
                        <Label class="menulabel">Information</Label>
                    </TableViewRow>
                    <TableViewRow class="menurowview">
                        <Label class="menulabel">Help</Label>
                    </TableViewRow>
                </TableView>
            </View> 
        </View>

        <View id="mainview">
            <View id="mainheaderview">
                <Button id="menubutton" onClick="showhidemenu"/>
                <Label id="mainheaderlabel">News</Label>
                <Button id="addbutton" />
            </View>
            <View id="mainbodyview" ></View>
        </View>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

and the controller:

```
var menuOpen = false;
function showhidemenu(e) {
    if (menuOpen) {
        moveTo = "0";
        menuOpen = false;
    } else {
        moveTo = "35%";
        menuOpen = true;
    }

    $.mainview.width = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
    $.mainview.animate({
        left : moveTo,
        curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_EASE_OUT,
        duration : 300
    });
};

function select(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.section.rows.length; i++) {
        e.section.rows[i].backgroundColor = '#212429';
    }

    var selectedRow = e.row;
    selectedRow.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    if ($.mainbodyview.children.length) {
        $.mainbodyview.removeAllChildren();
    }
    //*************add your view here*******************
    if (selectedRow.children[0].text == 'News') {
        $.mainheaderlabel.setText('News');
        $.addbutton.visible = false;
        $.mainbodyview.add(Alloy.createController('news').getView());
    } else if (selectedRow.children[0].text == 'Homework') {
        $.mainheaderlabel.setText('Homework');
        $.addbutton.visible = true;
        $.mainbodyview.add(Alloy.createController('homework').getView());
    } else if (selectedRow.children[0].text == 'Information') {
        $.mainheaderlabel.setText('Information');
        $.addbutton.visible = false;
        $.mainbodyview.add(new Alloy.createController('information').getView());
    } else if (selectedRow.children[0].text == 'Calendar') {
        $.mainheaderlabel.setText('Calendar');
        $.addbutton.visible = false;
        //$.mainbodyview.add(Alloy.createController('calendar').getView());
    } else if (selectedRow.children[0].text == 'Classes') {
        $.mainheaderlabel.setText('Classes');
        $.addbutton.visible = false;
        //$.mainbodyview.add(Alloy.createController('classes').getView());
    } else if (selectedRow.children[0].text == 'Help') {
        $.mainheaderlabel.setText('Help');
        $.addbutton.visible = false;
        $.mainbodyview.add(Alloy.createController('help').getView());
    } else {

    }
    //**************************************************
    showhidemenu();
};


$.index.open();
$.mainbodyview.add(Alloy.createController('news').getView());
```

The part of the code that is breaking on IOS is  `$.mainbodyview.add(Alloy.createController('news').getView());` 
and anything like it. It works perfectly on Android. Is there something I'm missing for it to be IOS compatible?

Comment: What's error message?

Comment: There's no error message, nothing loads into the mainbodyview.

Comment: Can you add your .tss file and screenshot from emulator?
It looks like all is working but view which you are loading are showing outside of screen that's why it looks like broken.
Make sure all elements are visible with changing their background color to something bright.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same issue.
I was using the window tag before which was working fine for Android but not for iPhone but then i change my 'Window' tag to 'View' tag in views. It start working fine for both Android and iPhone.